# MPI_Scatterv with only one thread

Tags: mpi

I got a quick question. Is it possible to use MPI_Scatterv() with only one thread which is of course also the root? It is not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: I know that with ```MPI_Broadcast``` and ```MPI_Reduce``` it is possible. Why don't you just try it? If it does not work post an example.

Comment: I have tried it and I am getting a segmentation error at the scatterv. I think it must have something to do with the parameters but unfortunately I can not post the code as I am not allowed to.

Comment: Can you at least post the relevant parts? Try to paste a small example

Comment: The code is confidential so that will not be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's fine as long as the communicator you are using also only contains this single process.